# Cannot mock method from boto3 (using botocore.stub.Stubber)

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-kms, botocore

In my `podcasts.py` I have at first lines:

```
kms = boto3.client('kms')
access_key = kms.decrypt(
    CiphertextBlob=base64.b64decode(os.environ['access_key'])
)['Plaintext'].decode()
```

According to the [docs](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/stubber.html), I tried to stub it in my `podcasts_test.py`:

```
import base64
import os

from botocore.stub import Stubber

os.environ['access_key'] = base64.b64encode('my_test_access_key'.encode()).decode()
client = boto3.client('kms')
stubber = Stubber(client)
stubber.add_response('decrypt', {'Plaintext': b'my_test_key'})
stubber.activate()

import podcasts_build
```

But I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "podcasts_build_test.py", line 14, in <module>
    import podcasts_build
  File "/Users/vitaly/intelligent-speaker/backend/lambdas/podcasts_build/podcasts_build.py", line 23, in <module>
    CiphertextBlob=base64.b64decode(os.environ['access_key'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 320, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 623, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidCiphertextException: An error occurred (InvalidCiphertextException) when calling the Decrypt operation:
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the cause of this is that the client is being re-defined after the Stubber is applied, and it's trying to hit the API for real.

This is a minimal example based on your question, so to get it working with your code you'll likely have to apply this principle more generally while refactoring. I would additionally consider using the [unittest framework](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html).

First, make it possible to pass a client instance into the code you're testing.

podcasts.py:

```
def decrypt_kms(kms_client):
    access_key = kms_client.decrypt(
        CiphertextBlob=base64.b64decode(os.environ['access_key'])
    )['Plaintext'].decode()
    return access_key
```

Then in your tests, create the stubbed client and pass it into the code to test

tests.py:

```
from botocore.stub import Stubber
from podcasts import decrypt_kms

kms_decrypt_response = {'Plaintext': 'my_test_key'}
stubbed_client = boto3.client('kms')
stubber = Stubber(stubbed_client)
stubber.add_response('decrypt', kms_decrypt_response)
stubber.activate()
result = decrypt_kms(kms_client=stubbed_client)
```

Comment: My mocked response was returned, but after that the same exception. Tried to `print()` response in my prod code that I want to test - no response.

Comment: Try re-writing your production code as a method that accepts a client instance. I'll update my answer.